# Why do we have negative length for character maximum length for geography and varchar(max) data types?

Tags: sql-server

Why do we have negative length for character maximum length for  geography and varchar(max) data types?

Character_Maximum_length = - 1

Answer (score 6):

The value -1 is a special value that means "maximum currently supported". The maximum length of e.g. `max`, `xml`, and `clr` types could change in a future version of SQL Server.

In system views like `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` the `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` column already uses `NULL` for types where a character length is not applicable, for example the numeric types.

If you are currently using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views, [you should read this](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views) and then consider using SQL Server's own metadata views like `sys.columns` instead.

As a side note, the underlying type of the `max_length` column in `sys.columns` is `smallint NOT NULL`. It is the maximum length (in bytes, *not characters*) of the column, or -1 meaning 'maximum supported` as mentioned before.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you'll get a good answer why, I suspect the person who made that decision didn't like NULLs, which would have been better IMHO.